# Why docker refuse to connect to 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, sequelize.js

my database url setting is

DATABASE_URL=postgres://DBUser:DBPass@locahost:5432/DatabaseName

my docker file is as below

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  db_command:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: pgDB
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: DBUser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: DBPass
      POSTGRES_DB: DatabaseName
    volumes:
      - "./.docker_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"  
    ports:  
      - "5432:5432"
```

when I try to run command `sequelize db:migrate` It throws an error

I can connect to postgres docker instance via command line not an issue.

`ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`
I do not understand changing the host from 127.0.0.1 to localhost is not effective. Also, this was running previously and now it's not working, which is very puzzling to me.

I have gone check out the solution but none is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access container B from container A, you can't use `localhost`, because container B is not running inside container A. It is in the network of containers.

Try specifying a container dependency using `depends_on`:

```
services:
  redis:
    ...<existing config>
    depends_on:
      - pgDB
```

Then the redis container can access the database container. Use the address of container B `0.0.0.0:5432` to connect.

Better yet, simply use the name of the container you are trying to access (`pgDB`)

Side note: Best practice is to not alter container names. Just let them use their service names if possible.

Comment: If I change that I get - ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pgDB

Comment: Updated my answer, `depends_on` is missing in your config.

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to run command sequelize db:migrate It throws an error

From where do you try to run the command ? the redis container ? your local ?

If it is from the redis container you can use the name of the service: `db_command`

Url : DATABASE_URL=postgres://DBUser:DBPass@db_command:5432/DatabaseName